# How can classical Hamiltonian mechanics be expressed as C*-algebra?

Tags: mathematical-physics, c-star-algebras, classical-mechanics

I am not able to find a proper explanation of how classical mechanics can be expressed as C*-algebra. In the brief description that I found (please see here below few references), it is said that classical mechanics is described as abelian $C^{*}$-algebra, but I missed how important steps as the representation of the phase space or the description of Poisson brakets are introduced. I asked this question also on Physics StackExchange, but no answer so far.

**References**

"Deterministic Chaos in Infinite Quantum Systems" by F. Benatti;

"Operator Algebras and Quantum Statistical Mechanics" by O. Bratteli, D. Robinson.

Comment: This is overstated, I think. The idea is to take the $C^{\ast}$-algebra of continuous functions on the cotangent bundle $T^{\ast}(X)$ where $X$ is some manifold that some particle is moving around in. The symplectic form on $T^{\ast}(X)$ gives a Poisson bracket on the *smooth* functions but as far as I know this bracket doesn't meaningfully extend to the entire $C^{\ast}$-algebra of continuous functions. Really we should be working with the smooth functions, which form what is called a smooth algebra: https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/C%5E%E2%88%9E-ring

Comment: @QiaochuYuan So it is not fully precise to say that classical mechanics can be representad as C*-algebra since on the continuous but not smooth functions on the manifold X the Poisson brakets are not properly defined. Am I saying right?

Comment: That's what I think, anyway.